# Understanding logic in CaseInsensitiveComparator

Tags: java, string, java-6

Can anyone explain the following code from `String.java`, specifically why there are three `if` statements (which I've marked `//1`, `//2` and `//3`)?

```
private static class CaseInsensitiveComparator
                     implements Comparator<String>, java.io.Serializable {
// use serialVersionUID from JDK 1.2.2 for interoperability
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8575799808933029326L;

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int n1=s1.length(), n2=s2.length();
        for (int i1=0, i2=0; i1<n1 && i2<n2; i1++, i2++) {
            char c1 = s1.charAt(i1);
            char c2 = s2.charAt(i2);
            if (c1 != c2) {/////////////////////////1
                c1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
                c2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
                if (c1 != c2) {/////////////////////////2
                    c1 = Character.toLowerCase(c1);
                    c2 = Character.toLowerCase(c2);
                    if (c1 != c2) {/////////////////////////3
                        return c1 - c2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return n1 - n2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed yet a third identical `if` statement!

Comment: You missed one, there is a third one after the toLowerCase calls

Comment: If you are talking about the lines with `//1` and `//2` (I skimmed through the post too quickly when answering), then there isn't anything interesting. The interesting part is why there are double conversion.

Comment: @nhahtdh actually i mean that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Normally, we would expect to convert the case once and compare and be done with it. However, the code convert the case twice, and the reason is stated in the comment on a different method [`public boolean regionMatches(boolean ignoreCase, int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.regionMatches%28boolean%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cint%29):

> Unfortunately, conversion to uppercase does not work properly for the Georgian alphabet, which has strange rules about case conversion.  So we need to make one last check before exiting.

---

#### Appendix

The code of `regionMatches` has a few difference from the code in the `CaseInsenstiveComparator`, but essentially does the same thing. The full code of the method is quoted below for the purpose of cross-checking:

```
public boolean regionMatches(boolean ignoreCase, int toffset,
                       String other, int ooffset, int len) {
    char ta[] = value;
    int to = offset + toffset;
    char pa[] = other.value;
    int po = other.offset + ooffset;
    // Note: toffset, ooffset, or len might be near -1>>>1.
    if ((ooffset < 0) || (toffset < 0) || (toffset > (long)count - len) ||
            (ooffset > (long)other.count - len)) {
        return false;
    }
    while (len-- > 0) {
        char c1 = ta[to++];
        char c2 = pa[po++];
        if (c1 == c2) {
            continue;
        }
        if (ignoreCase) {
            // If characters don't match but case may be ignored,
            // try converting both characters to uppercase.
            // If the results match, then the comparison scan should
            // continue.
            char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
            char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
            if (u1 == u2) {
                continue;
            }
            // Unfortunately, conversion to uppercase does not work properly
            // for the Georgian alphabet, which has strange rules about case
            // conversion.  So we need to make one last check before
            // exiting.
            if (Character.toLowerCase(u1) == Character.toLowerCase(u2)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you posted this; I was a little mystified about why we converted to upper case *and* lower case.  Now I have my answer!

Comment: Well done for finding out the answer to the lowercase statement. I think you've got the best answer here.

Answer (score 42):

From [Unicode Technical Standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Simple_Loose_Matches):

> In addition, because of the vagaries of natural language, there are situations where two different Unicode characters have the same uppercase or lowercase

So, it's not enough to compare only uppercase of two characters, because they may have different uppercase and same lowercase

Simple brute force check gives some results. Check for example code points 73 and 304:

```
char ch1 = (char) 73; //LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
char ch2 = (char) 304; //LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE
System.out.println(ch1==ch2);
System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(ch1)==Character.toUpperCase(ch2));
System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(ch1)==Character.toLowerCase(ch2));
```

Output:

```
false
false
true
```

So "İ" and "I" are not equal to each other. Both characters are uppercase. But they share the same lower case letter: "i" and that gives a reason to treat them as same values in case insensitive comparison.

Comment: This is also a useful answer to the question people might have when they first read the docs for String.compareToIgnoreCase, and notice the "case differences have been eliminated by calling Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(character))" bit.

Comment: This is why code that assumes you can uppercase only and compare two strings is wrong if performed in the user's locale.

Answer (score 22):

In another answer, default locale already gave an example for why comparing only uppercase is not enough, namely the ASCII letter "I" and the capital I with dot "İ".

Now you might wonder, **why do they not just compare only lowercase instead of both upper and lower case, if it catches more cases than uppercase?** The answer is, it does not catch *more* cases, it merely finds *different* cases.

Take the letter "ı" (`(char)305`, small dotless i) and the ascii "i". They are different, their lowercase is different, but they share the same uppercase letter "I".

And finally, compare capital I with dot "İ" with small dotless i "ı". Neither their uppercases ("İ" vs. "I") nor their lowercases ("i" vs. "ı") matches, but the lowercase of their uppercase is the same ("I"). I found another case if this phenomenon, in the greek letters "ϴ" and "ϑ" (char 1012 and 977).

So a true case insensitive comparison can not even check uppercases and lowercases *of the original characters*, but must check the lowercases of the uppercases.

Comment: Finally, somebody posted examples sufficient to justify this algorithm. Great answer, +1. I'll just leave here brute-force code that generates sample code points: http://ideone.com/t6Seo4

Comment: Is there any reason not to define a "toCanonical" function which would define, for any character, a single canonical form so that invoking `toCanonical` on two characters would yield the same result only if they should be equivalent in a case-sensitive comparison?  That would seem more efficient than requiring calls to `toUpper` and `toLower`.

Comment: Correct answer. But show us some code to examplify how you would implement this...

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following characters: `f` and `F`. The initial `if` statement would return `false` because they don't match. However, if you capitalise both characters, you get `F` and `F`. Then they would match. The same would not be true of, say, `c` and `G`.

The code is efficient. There is no need to capitalise both characters if they already match (hence the first `if` statement). However, if they don't match, we need to check if they differ only in case (hence the second `if` statement).

The final `if` statement is used for certain alphabets (such as Georgian) where capitalisation is a complicated affair. To be honest, I don't know a great deal about how that works (just trust that Oracle does!).

Answer (score 0):

In the above case for case insensitive comparison assume **s1="Apple" and s2="apple"**
In this case 'A'!='a' as the ascii values of both the characters are different then it changes both the Characters to upper case and again compares then the loop continues to get the final value of n1-n2=0 thus the strings become the same.Suppose if the characters are not equal at all the second check

```
if (c1 != c2) {
return c1 - c2;
}
```

returns the difference in ascii value of the two characters.