# How to use `string.startsWith()` method ignoring the case?

Tags: java, string

I want to use `string.startsWith()` method but ignoring the case.

Suppose I have `String` "Session" and I use `startsWith` on "sEsSi" then it should return `true`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There was no reason to close this question.  Anyway, the best solution is to use `string.regionMatches(true, 0, prefix, 0, prefix.length());` which doesn't incur the cost of "normalizing" both strings.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Fine by me.  The correct answer is posted in my comment above.  It is much more efficient than changing the case of strings.  It'd be good to upgrade it to an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` to standardise your string before testing it.

Comment: The big problem here is the performance.
For small Strings no problem, but if you have a big one... I mean... Do you really will do a toUpperCase in a 1mb String just to compare 4-10 inicial characters?

Comment: Hum even if i can't see why i would like to compare the starting part of a 1mb String then if only 4 - 10 initial characters interest me i use substring and then normalize and done...

Comment: This answer (and all other answers found herein) are wrong. If you look at the implementation of `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` you will discover that you need to compare **both** lowercase and uppercase versions of the Strings before you can conclusively return `false`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38947571/14731 for an alternative answer.

Comment: Hum if you have uped your string and then test agains an upped prefix i can't see when this will fail. Ii seem's to me that's what 'standardise a string' means... I used it many times with no error in real life projects.

Comment: This answer is not true because toLowerCase() uses Locale.getDefault() internally to change the chars and that might lead to false negatives. Let's say you want to compare "İstanbul" with "istanbul". In Turkish "İ" s lower case equivalent is "ı". So when I try to do that `"İstanbul".toLowerCase().startsWith("istanbul".toLowerCase())` (in a Locale.Turkish environment), it will give me false.

Comment: @Nemesis, This answer is wrong, having it as the accepted answer could be misleading for a lot of people. Would you please edit your answer and link to Rohit Jain answer.

Comment: This is a wrong answer since the original value should not be changed for a conditional function.

Answer (score 102):

<strike>One option is to convert both of them to either lowercase or uppercase:</strike>

```
"Session".toLowerCase().startsWith("sEsSi".toLowerCase());
```

This is wrong. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15518878/14731

---

Another option is to use [`String#regionMatches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches%28boolean,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) method, which takes a boolean argument stating whether to do case-sensitive matching or not. You can use it like this:

```
String haystack = "Session";
String needle = "sEsSi";
System.out.println(haystack.regionMatches(true, 0, needle, 0, needle.length()));  // true
```

It checks whether the region of `needle` from index `0` till length `5` is present in `haystack` starting from index `0` till length `5` or not. The first argument is `true`, means it will do case-insensitive matching.

---

And if only you are a big fan of ***Regex***, you can do something like this:

```
System.out.println(haystack.matches("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(needle) + ".*"));
```

`(?i)` embedded flag is for ignore case matching.

Comment: Actually, suppose there is a table which is having more than 1 lakh entries , and I use a for loop on particular column to parse all those entries and in that, I try to use this lowercase option above to search an entry starting with particular pattern. So, this is causing a performance issue. If there is no match found at all, then internally it will parse through all the entries, which will take lot of time, as simultaneously its getting converted to lowercase as well. So is there any other option, to resolve performance issue?

Comment: @Rohit Jain, actually this:
 `System.out.println("Session".toLowerCase().startsWith("sEsSi".toLowerCase()));` is not a propper solution.

You can try this: 
 `System.out.println("SessIon".toLowerCase().startsWith("sEsSi".toLowerCase()));`
with vm arguments `-Duser.country=TR -Duser.language=tr` 
In this example the `I` is uppercase `i`

Answer (score 23):

I know I'm late, but what about using StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase() from Apache Commons Lang 3 ?

Example :

```
StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(string, "start");
```

Just add the following dependency to your pom.xml file (taking the hypothesis that you use Maven) :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Perfect -- thank you.  This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
myString.StartsWith(anotherString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: The question is about Java, not .NET/C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
myString.toLowerCase().startsWith(starting.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
String session = "Session";
if(session.toLowerCase().startsWith("sEsSi".toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `someString.toUpperCase().startsWith(someOtherString.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.search() function with regex that will give you the index of the first substring match of the search string. Then you can test the returned index to see if it is 0. 'i' at the end makes the search case insensitive.

```
const session = 'Session';
const startsWith = session.search(/sEsSi/i) === 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can always do

```
"Session".toLowerCase().startsWith("sEsSi".toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score -3):

StartsWith(String value, bool ignoreCase, CultureInfo? culture)
e.g:

```
string test = "Session";
bool result = test.StartsWith("sEsSi", true, null);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

point: in VS by right-clicking on StartsWith and then "pick definition" can see all overloading method

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question is about java.