# String.equalsIgnoreCase - UpperCase v. LowerCase

Tags: string, equals, java

I was browsing through the openjdk and noticed a weird code path in String.equalsIgnoreCase, specifically the method [regionMatches](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#1331):

```
if (ignoreCase) {
    // If characters don't match but case may be ignored,
    // try converting both characters to uppercase.
    // If the results match, then the comparison scan should
    // continue.
    char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
    char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
    if (u1 == u2) {
        continue;
    }
    // Unfortunately, conversion to uppercase does not work properly
    // for the Georgian alphabet, which has strange rules about case
    // conversion.  So we need to make one last check before
    // exiting.
    if (Character.toLowerCase(u1) == Character.toLowerCase(u2)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

I understand the comment about adjusting for a specific alphabet to check the lower case equality, but was wondering why even have the upper case check? Why not just do all lower case?

Comment: Are you asking that instead of using `toUpperCase()` why didn't they use `toLowerCase()`?

Comment: This question seems to be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518731/understanding-logic-in-caseinsensitivecomparator

Comment: My guess is that `toLowerCase` would have a similar problem: if it failed you would then need to try `toUpperCase`. It's just a coin toss which one is done first.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes. Why even have the toUpperCase checks?

Comment: @DanW Well if the case is ignored, they'll have to be both either uppercase or lower case to test for similarity, won't they?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm just asking why have the upper case check if it appears by the comment that lower case handles more cases. However, as  TedHopp points out, there's probably a similar issue with toLowerCase.

Comment: @DanW The comment talks about "strange rules about case conversion". It says nothing about lower case handling more cases.

Comment: @EJP Why was this marked as a duplicate? The suggested duplicate post just points to the same line of code I questioned about. It does not say why the toUpperCase check is needed. And if there is a situation where toLowerCase would return false for a check where toUpperCase works, that is not cited.

Comment: The other post does not ask the same question and none of the answers say why toLowerCase isn't used solely. There's no mention of another alphabet having issues with toUpperCase -- that's only being assumed by some commenters here. Not a duplicate in answer or question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25513639/900873

Comment: @Kevin If you want to post that I'll accept as the answer.

Comment: @Kevin Worth noting that answer was added on hour ago and didn't exist when this question was asked. Glad to see it answered, though.

Comment: But *this* question is now a duplicate since its answer is one of the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518731/understanding-logic-in-caseinsensitivecomparator

Comment: @DanW Cristian Semrau [already provided a counterexample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25513639/451518). Actually, you can use simplistic brute force check to search for code points that satisfy given conditions. Take a look on the code here: http://ideone.com/DgPx23

Comment: @defaultlocale Yes, I see that now. However, that answer was posted after I asked this question, it got closed, and then re-opened.

Comment: @defaultlocale I indented to give my answer to this question. :-) It got closed while I was preparing my answer, so I answered the other question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Now that the question is re-opened, I transfer my answer here.

The short answer to "Why do they not just compare only lowercase instead of both upper and lower case, if it matches more cases than uppercase?": It does not match *more* character pairs, it merely matches *different* pairs.

Comparing only uppercase is not enough, e.g. the ASCII letter "I" and the capital I with dot "İ" (`(char)304`, used in Turkish alphabet) have different uppercase (they are already uppercase), but they have the same lowercase letter "i". (Note that the Turkish language considers i with dot and i without dot as different letters, not just an accented letter, similar to German with its Umlauts ä/ö/ü vs. a/o/u.)

Comparing only lowercase is not enough, e.g. the ASCII letter "i" and the small dotless i "ı" (`(char)305`). They have different lowercase (they are already lowercase), but they have the same uppercase letter "I".

And finally, compare capital I with dot "İ" with small dotless i "ı". Neither their uppercases ("İ" vs. "I") nor their lowercases ("i" vs. "ı") match, but the lowercase of their uppercase is the same ("I"). I found another case if this phenomenon, in the greek letters "ϴ" and "ϑ" (char 1012 and 977).

So a true case insensitive comparison can not even check uppercases and lowercases of the original characters, but must check the lowercases of the uppercases.

Comment: This is a modified copy of my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25513639/282229

Comment: Thank you for porting your answer over.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you twi... Oh, wait a minute... :)