# Curious about the implementation of CaseInsensitiveComparator

Tags: java, string, comparator

While I check the implementation of `CaseInsensitiveComparator`, which is private inner class of `String`, I found strange thing.

```
private static class CaseInsensitiveComparator
        implements Comparator<String>, java.io.Serializable {
    ...
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int n1 = s1.length();
        int n2 = s2.length();
        int min = Math.min(n1, n2);
        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
            char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
            if (c1 != c2) {
                c1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
                c2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
                if (c1 != c2) {
                    c1 = Character.toLowerCase(c1);
                    c2 = Character.toLowerCase(c2);
                    if (c1 != c2) {
                        // No overflow because of numeric promotion
                        return c1 - c2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return n1 - n2;
    }
    ...
}
```

What I'm curious is this: In the `for` loop, once you compare the upper cased characters, why you should compare the lower cased characters again? When `Character.toUpperCase(c1)` and `Character.toUpperCase(c2)` are different, is it possible that `Character.toLowerCase(c1)` and `Character.toLowerCase(c2)` are equal?

Couldn't it be simplified like this?

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    int n1 = s1.length();
    int n2 = s2.length();
    int min = Math.min(n1, n2);
    for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
        char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
        char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
        if (c1 != c2) {
            c1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
            c2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
            if (c1 != c2) {
                // No overflow because of numeric promotion
                return c1 - c2;
            }
        }
    }
    return n1 - n2;
}
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25513639/2336725) to the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are Unicode characters which are different in lowercase, but have the same uppercase form. For example the Greek letter Sigma - it has two lowercase forms (σ, and ς which is only used at the end of the word), but only one uppercase form (Σ).

I could not find any examples of the reverse, but if such a situation happened in the future, the current Java implementation is already prepared for this. Your version of the `Comparator` would definitely handle the Sigma case correctly.

You can find more information in the [Case Mapping FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#7a) on the Unicode website.

Comment: The common german character `ß` only exists in its lower case form, and would be `SS` in upper case.

Comment: @maja "SS" are two characters. This conversion is only performed on strings, not on single characters.

Comment: Actually, uppercase ß (ẞ) was added to the Universal Character Set in 2008: https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_ẞ However, even though it become mandatory for names of geographical places in official government documents in 2010, I haven't seen a single one in the wild.

Comment: +1, although you actually explain the opposit problem than the question asked for: inequal upper case characters may also map to the same lower case character, that is why this check is present in a CaseInsesitiveComparator.

Comment: Yes, I realized that afterwards (and updated my answer). However, the Sigma-case is probably the most elegant and well-known example of the non-injectiveness of the uppercase function. For the lowercase function, I couldn't find a good example.

Comment: (I remember having heard stories about Turkish `İ` Latin `I` both mapping to Latin`i`, and I think something about mathematical symbol my vs. Greek)

Comment: There is also Turkish lowercase dotless i vs. Latin lowercase dotted i. They are different, but both are uppercased to uppercase dotless i.

Comment: German ß is tricky. It should compare equal to ss for most purposes. Its use in uppercase form should be avoided, so for example with Main Street = Hauptstraße you should avoid HAUPTSTRASSE. What's worse there are a few cases where there is one word with ß and another with ss with totally different meaning; in that case ß should be capitalised to SZ. But with purely case insensitive comparison, it should be different from any other character.

Comment: @gnasher729 AFAIR the SZ rule was dropped around 2006 or so, when we were blessed with the new orthography.

Comment: @Hulk There are Turkish locales which male the upper/lower case conversion beave differently.

Comment: @glglgl I didn't know that, but it doesn't surprise me. I am aware that the mapping has "collisions" in both directions and that it does depend on the locale and other things - as Glorfindel has pointed out, position within the word and neighboring chars may have an effect as well.